# UI lag from updating textview with countdown timer and having a textview marquee on the same activity

Tags: java, android

I have a textView that displays the progress of a countdown timer and I also have another textView that I have set to marquee when ever the length is too long that is gotten from user input. When the marquee animation is occurring and the timer is active, the UI lags. How can prevent the lag and still have UI update respectively

code for the timer:

```
  countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliSeconds+100, 1000)
    {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                milliSecTime = (int) millisUntilFinished;
                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds


                String hms = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), 
                          "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
                                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

                countDownTimerTextView.setText(hms);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                beepSoundStop.start();
                countDownTimerTextView.setText(R.string.time);

                countNumberOfSets = countNumberOfSets + 1;
                setsTextView.setText(countNumberOfSets + "/" + tNumberOfSets);
                Log.i("CountNumberOfSets", String.valueOf(countNumberOfSets));
                restTimerActive = false;
                timerIsActive = false;
                getNewWorkout();
                Log.i("REST TIMER FINISHED", "TRUE");

            }
        }.start();
```

Here is the java code for the marquee:

```
       workoutNameTextView =  findViewById(R.id.workoutNameTextView);
       workoutNameTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Here is the xml for the textView:

```
                       <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/workoutNameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/stopFab"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/startAndPauseFAB"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="@string/workout"
                        android:textAlignment="center"

                        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/workoutNameTextSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I know these are processes that are both running on the main thread of the UI but how can I make them occur concurrently to prevent the lag

Comment: you should use some `AsyncTask` or something

Comment: but you see they need to happen at the same time sure I can override the do in background but on postExecute I'll have to call the mainthread to update